# Smack chats creating two threads

Tags: java, smack

I'm having trouble establishing a proper chat in the Smack messaging library for Java. It works just fine if the chat was started locally, but if the chat is started from another client then two different chat threads are created, instead of just the one that is needed. My code for sending a message is below:

```
public void sendMessage(String input) throws XMPPException 
    {
        Chat chat = connection.getChatManager().getThreadChat("test@server");
        if(chat != null)
        {
            System.out.println("Chat exists!");
            chat.addMessageListener(messageListener);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Create new chat");
            chat = connection.getChatManager().createChat("test@server", "test@server", messageListener);
        System.out.println(chat.getThreadID());
        }
        chat.sendMessage(input);
    }
```

Below I have my listener class which processes incoming messages. It is originally set up when the program is initialized so that messages can be recieved straight after log in, and chats established. It is also called by the `messageListener` variable in the `sendMessage` function you can see above.

```
class MyMessageListener implements MessageListener {
        @Override
        public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {
            String from = message.getFrom();
            String body = message.getBody();
            System.out.println(chat.getThreadID());
            System.out.println(String.format("Received message '%1$s' from %2$s", body, from));    
        }
    }
```

I'm very new to the Smack library and finding the available documentation and examples a bit vague. Anyone have any pointers as to how I could check if a chat was created on another client and somehow fetch the thread ID of this chat or find a chat object from the ChatManager by knowing the name of the user that sent the message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to register a **ChatManagerListener** to listen for incoming chats, as described in the [Incoming Chats](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/messaging.html) section in documentation.  A listener on a chat created this way will receive the incoming messages, assuming they are responding with the same thread id (not all clients use a thread id).

By the way, you are looking up an existing chat by thread, but that is not a the thread id of an incoming chat.  The code snippet you have shown will only match on the chat that you have created yourself, so there is no point in setting the message listener every time you are going to send a message, you may as well just hold a reference to it once it is create.

You will have to retrieve the thread id from the incoming chat to have this work properly, and that is assuming that the incoming chat actually has a chat id.

Comment: I have the ChatManagerListener in the code, probably something I should have mentioned in the question but it is there.
I'm aware of the problem with my getThreadChat() call but I've been having trouble finding a better solution. I've looked into the getUserChat() call you mentioned and not finding information on it and it's not in the documentation as far as I can see. Is this a call from the ChatManager? I'm not getting any option to fetch a chat through JID unfortunately.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply. I had another project due and had to shift my work focus to meet my deadlines. Most of what your answer suggested I already had implemented in my code, but your suggestion was correct. I was not properly holding a reference to the thread ID of my chats. Seems to be working very well now, and each chat lives by one thread ID. Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: I had similar issue. The problem I had is that I was opening chat like this: `this.connection.getChatManager().createChat(chatroom, listener);` and I was expecting the messages to arrive to this instance. BUT after reading manual `Incoming connections` sections, I realized proper approach.